# Почему метод Convert.ToString(num,2) убирает нули перед числами в двоичной системе?

Tags: c#

Почему при конвертировании чисел в двоичную систему методом

```
Convert.ToString(num,2)
```

убираются нули перед числом?

Например: 1 -> 1,2 -> 10, 3-> 11, 4 ->100, 5 -> 101 и т.д.

Я в чем-то допускаю ошибку или так и задумано? Как это исправить?

Comment: И вы наверное можете обяснить машине, сколько вы как художник видите нулей перед числом? Минимальная запись числа предусматривает скрывать все ведущие нули, все до одного. А если вам нужно форматированное представление - вы можете число показать с разбивкой по группам, указать формат разделителя, сколько ведущих нулей показывать и т.п. Хотите три нуля? Два нуля? Число останется тем же самым! Поэтому у вас должно быть две операции: собственно конвертация и возможно, отображение на экране в нужном формате.

Comment: @AK Может и останется,но принятый двоичный вид чисел всегда выглядел так : 0001, 0010,0011 и т.д. Он мне и нужен

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netcore-2.0

Comment: `int[] a = new int[3] {10,11,1};
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++){
                Console.WriteLine(a[i].ToString("0000"));
            }`

Comment: `0001` - это четыре бита. А если нужно отобразить 32-битное число? Остальные биты отбросить (число может стать не тем)? Или всегда их показывать: `00000000000000000000000000000001`? Удобно, правда?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Дополнил ответ алгоритмом расчёта сколько нужно цифр в формате.

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужна функция PadLeft для форматирования:

```
int value = 3;
string result = Convert.ToString(value, 2); // конвертация
string formatted = result.PadLeft(8, '0'); // форматирование: 00000011
//formatted.Dump();
```

Вообще, с двоичной системой больше засада: для десятичной и 16тиричной есть уже готовые форматтеры:

```
int value = 11;
string formattedDecimal = value.ToString("D8"); // 00000011
string formattedHexadecimal = value.ToString("X8"); 0000000B
```

В целом же вам нужно понять, что фаза конвертации и фаза форматирования числа (в выбранной локализации с выбранным форматом) - это совершенно разные операции и их нужно разделять.

Очень любопытный вопрос задали в комментариях, вспомним степени и логарифмы:

> А если при конвертировании будет больше 8 символов? Например value = 507;

Построим такую табличку:

> ```
> Строка  От     До   Число символов
>
> 0        0     15                4
>
> 1       16    255                8
>
> 2      256   1023               12
> ```

Видим следующие закономерности:

- искомое число символов - это 4 + 4 * i (где i - это номер строки)
- переход на новую строку происходит когда value достигает 4 в степени 2 * i

Значит (прологарифмировав по основанию 4 обе части выражения value = 4 ^ 2 * i получим расчётную формулу для i) окончательно:

```
public int GetPow(int value)
{
    if(value == 0)
        return 4;

    var i = 0.5 * Math.Log(value, 4);
    return (int) i * 4 + 4;
}
```

Кому интересно проверить - запустить такую программку:

```
void Main()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 1026; i++)
        this.Sample(i);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public void Sample(int value)
{
    string result = Convert.ToString(value, 2);
    int pow = this.GetPow(value);
    string formatted = result.PadLeft(this.GetPow(value), '0');
    $"value = {value.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')}, pow={pow.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')}, formatted = {formatted}".Dump();
}
```

Вывод (с сокращениями):

```
value = 0000, pow=0004, formatted = 0000
value = 0001, pow=0004, formatted = 0001
value = 0002, pow=0004, formatted = 0010
value = 0003, pow=0004, formatted = 0011
value = 0004, pow=0004, formatted = 0100
value = 0005, pow=0004, formatted = 0101
value = 0006, pow=0004, formatted = 0110
value = 0007, pow=0004, formatted = 0111
value = 0008, pow=0004, formatted = 1000
value = 0009, pow=0004, formatted = 1001
value = 0010, pow=0004, formatted = 1010
value = 0011, pow=0004, formatted = 1011
value = 0012, pow=0004, formatted = 1100
value = 0013, pow=0004, formatted = 1101
value = 0014, pow=0004, formatted = 1110
value = 0015, pow=0004, formatted = 1111
value = 0016, pow=0008, formatted = 00010000
value = 0017, pow=0008, formatted = 00010001
value = 0018, pow=0008, formatted = 00010010
value = 0019, pow=0008, formatted = 00010011
value = 0020, pow=0008, formatted = 00010100
value = 0021, pow=0008, formatted = 00010101
value = 0022, pow=0008, formatted = 00010110
value = 0023, pow=0008, formatted = 00010111
value = 0024, pow=0008, formatted = 00011000
value = 0025, pow=0008, formatted = 00011001
value = 0026, pow=0008, formatted = 00011010
value = 0027, pow=0008, formatted = 00011011
value = 0028, pow=0008, formatted = 00011100
value = 0029, pow=0008, formatted = 00011101
value = 0030, pow=0008, formatted = 00011110
value = 0031, pow=0008, formatted = 00011111
value = 0032, pow=0008, formatted = 00100000
value = 0033, pow=0008, formatted = 00100001
value = 0034, pow=0008, formatted = 00100010
value = 0035, pow=0008, formatted = 00100011
value = 0036, pow=0008, formatted = 00100100
value = 0037, pow=0008, formatted = 00100101
value = 0038, pow=0008, formatted = 00100110
value = 0039, pow=0008, formatted = 00100111
value = 0040, pow=0008, formatted = 00101000
value = 0041, pow=0008, formatted = 00101001
value = 0042, pow=0008, formatted = 00101010
value = 0043, pow=0008, formatted = 00101011
value = 0044, pow=0008, formatted = 00101100
value = 0045, pow=0008, formatted = 00101101
value = 0046, pow=0008, formatted = 00101110
value = 0047, pow=0008, formatted = 00101111
value = 0048, pow=0008, formatted = 00110000
value = 0049, pow=0008, formatted = 00110001
value = 0050, pow=0008, formatted = 00110010
value = 0051, pow=0008, formatted = 00110011
value = 0052, pow=0008, formatted = 00110100
value = 0053, pow=0008, formatted = 00110101
value = 0054, pow=0008, formatted = 00110110
value = 0055, pow=0008, formatted = 00110111
value = 0056, pow=0008, formatted = 00111000
value = 0057, pow=0008, formatted = 00111001
value = 0058, pow=0008, formatted = 00111010
value = 0059, pow=0008, formatted = 00111011
value = 0060, pow=0008, formatted = 00111100
value = 0061, pow=0008, formatted = 00111101
value = 0062, pow=0008, formatted = 00111110
value = 0063, pow=0008, formatted = 00111111
value = 0064, pow=0008, formatted = 01000000
value = 0065, pow=0008, formatted = 01000001
value = 0066, pow=0008, formatted = 01000010
value = 0067, pow=0008, formatted = 01000011
value = 0068, pow=0008, formatted = 01000100
value = 0069, pow=0008, formatted = 01000101
value = 0070, pow=0008, formatted = 01000110
value = 0071, pow=0008, formatted = 01000111
value = 0072, pow=0008, formatted = 01001000
value = 0073, pow=0008, formatted = 01001001
value = 0074, pow=0008, formatted = 01001010
value = 0075, pow=0008, formatted = 01001011
value = 0076, pow=0008, formatted = 01001100
value = 0077, pow=0008, formatted = 01001101
value = 0078, pow=0008, formatted = 01001110
value = 0079, pow=0008, formatted = 01001111
value = 0080, pow=0008, formatted = 01010000
value = 0081, pow=0008, formatted = 01010001
value = 0082, pow=0008, formatted = 01010010
value = 0083, pow=0008, formatted = 01010011
value = 0084, pow=0008, formatted = 01010100
value = 0085, pow=0008, formatted = 01010101
value = 0086, pow=0008, formatted = 01010110
value = 0087, pow=0008, formatted = 01010111
value = 0088, pow=0008, formatted = 01011000
value = 0089, pow=0008, formatted = 01011001
value = 0090, pow=0008, formatted = 01011010
value = 0091, pow=0008, formatted = 01011011
value = 0092, pow=0008, formatted = 01011100
value = 0093, pow=0008, formatted = 01011101
value = 0094, pow=0008, formatted = 01011110
value = 0095, pow=0008, formatted = 01011111
value = 0096, pow=0008, formatted = 01100000
value = 0097, pow=0008, formatted = 01100001
value = 0098, pow=0008, formatted = 01100010
value = 0099, pow=0008, formatted = 01100011
value = 0100, pow=0008, formatted = 01100100
value = 0101, pow=0008, formatted = 01100101
value = 0102, pow=0008, formatted = 01100110
value = 0103, pow=0008, formatted = 01100111
value = 0104, pow=0008, formatted = 01101000
value = 0105, pow=0008, formatted = 01101001
value = 0106, pow=0008, formatted = 01101010
value = 0107, pow=0008, formatted = 01101011
value = 0108, pow=0008, formatted = 01101100
value = 0109, pow=0008, formatted = 01101101
value = 0110, pow=0008, formatted = 01101110
value = 0111, pow=0008, formatted = 01101111
value = 0112, pow=0008, formatted = 01110000
value = 0113, pow=0008, formatted = 01110001
value = 0114, pow=0008, formatted = 01110010
value = 0115, pow=0008, formatted = 01110011
value = 0116, pow=0008, formatted = 01110100
value = 0117, pow=0008, formatted = 01110101
value = 0118, pow=0008, formatted = 01110110
value = 0119, pow=0008, formatted = 01110111
value = 0120, pow=0008, formatted = 01111000
value = 0121, pow=0008, formatted = 01111001
value = 0122, pow=0008, formatted = 01111010
value = 0123, pow=0008, formatted = 01111011
value = 0124, pow=0008, formatted = 01111100
value = 0125, pow=0008, formatted = 01111101
value = 0126, pow=0008, formatted = 01111110
value = 0127, pow=0008, formatted = 01111111
value = 0128, pow=0008, formatted = 10000000
value = 0129, pow=0008, formatted = 10000001
value = 0130, pow=0008, formatted = 10000010
value = 0131, pow=0008, formatted = 10000011
value = 0132, pow=0008, formatted = 10000100
value = 0133, pow=0008, formatted = 10000101
value = 0134, pow=0008, formatted = 10000110
value = 0135, pow=0008, formatted = 10000111
value = 0136, pow=0008, formatted = 10001000
value = 0137, pow=0008, formatted = 10001001
value = 0138, pow=0008, formatted = 10001010
value = 0139, pow=0008, formatted = 10001011
value = 0140, pow=0008, formatted = 10001100
value = 0141, pow=0008, formatted = 10001101
value = 0142, pow=0008, formatted = 10001110
value = 0143, pow=0008, formatted = 10001111
value = 0144, pow=0008, formatted = 10010000
value = 0145, pow=0008, formatted = 10010001
value = 0146, pow=0008, formatted = 10010010
value = 0147, pow=0008, formatted = 10010011
value = 0148, pow=0008, formatted = 10010100
value = 0149, pow=0008, formatted = 10010101
value = 0150, pow=0008, formatted = 10010110
value = 0151, pow=0008, formatted = 10010111
value = 0152, pow=0008, formatted = 10011000
value = 0153, pow=0008, formatted = 10011001
value = 0154, pow=0008, formatted = 10011010
value = 0155, pow=0008, formatted = 10011011
value = 0156, pow=0008, formatted = 10011100
value = 0157, pow=0008, formatted = 10011101
value = 0158, pow=0008, formatted = 10011110
value = 0159, pow=0008, formatted = 10011111
value = 0160, pow=0008, formatted = 10100000
value = 0161, pow=0008, formatted = 10100001
value = 0162, pow=0008, formatted = 10100010
value = 0163, pow=0008, formatted = 10100011
value = 0164, pow=0008, formatted = 10100100
value = 0165, pow=0008, formatted = 10100101
value = 0166, pow=0008, formatted = 10100110
value = 0167, pow=0008, formatted = 10100111
value = 0168, pow=0008, formatted = 10101000
value = 0169, pow=0008, formatted = 10101001
value = 0170, pow=0008, formatted = 10101010
value = 0171, pow=0008, formatted = 10101011
value = 0172, pow=0008, formatted = 10101100
value = 0173, pow=0008, formatted = 10101101
value = 0174, pow=0008, formatted = 10101110
value = 0175, pow=0008, formatted = 10101111
value = 0176, pow=0008, formatted = 10110000
value = 0177, pow=0008, formatted = 10110001
value = 0178, pow=0008, formatted = 10110010
value = 0179, pow=0008, formatted = 10110011
value = 0180, pow=0008, formatted = 10110100
value = 0181, pow=0008, formatted = 10110101
value = 0182, pow=0008, formatted = 10110110
value = 0183, pow=0008, formatted = 10110111
value = 0184, pow=0008, formatted = 10111000
value = 0185, pow=0008, formatted = 10111001
value = 0186, pow=0008, formatted = 10111010
value = 0187, pow=0008, formatted = 10111011
value = 0188, pow=0008, formatted = 10111100
value = 0189, pow=0008, formatted = 10111101
value = 0190, pow=0008, formatted = 10111110
value = 0191, pow=0008, formatted = 10111111
value = 0192, pow=0008, formatted = 11000000
value = 0193, pow=0008, formatted = 11000001
value = 0194, pow=0008, formatted = 11000010
value = 0195, pow=0008, formatted = 11000011
value = 0196, pow=0008, formatted = 11000100
value = 0197, pow=0008, formatted = 11000101
value = 0198, pow=0008, formatted = 11000110
value = 0199, pow=0008, formatted = 11000111
value = 0200, pow=0008, formatted = 11001000
value = 0201, pow=0008, formatted = 11001001
value = 0202, pow=0008, formatted = 11001010
value = 0203, pow=0008, formatted = 11001011
value = 0204, pow=0008, formatted = 11001100
value = 0205, pow=0008, formatted = 11001101
value = 0206, pow=0008, formatted = 11001110
value = 0207, pow=0008, formatted = 11001111
value = 0208, pow=0008, formatted = 11010000
value = 0209, pow=0008, formatted = 11010001
value = 0210, pow=0008, formatted = 11010010
value = 0211, pow=0008, formatted = 11010011
value = 0212, pow=0008, formatted = 11010100
value = 0213, pow=0008, formatted = 11010101
value = 0214, pow=0008, formatted = 11010110
value = 0215, pow=0008, formatted = 11010111
value = 0216, pow=0008, formatted = 11011000
value = 0217, pow=0008, formatted = 11011001
value = 0218, pow=0008, formatted = 11011010
value = 0219, pow=0008, formatted = 11011011
value = 0220, pow=0008, formatted = 11011100
value = 0221, pow=0008, formatted = 11011101
value = 0222, pow=0008, formatted = 11011110
value = 0223, pow=0008, formatted = 11011111
value = 0224, pow=0008, formatted = 11100000
value = 0225, pow=0008, formatted = 11100001
value = 0226, pow=0008, formatted = 11100010
value = 0227, pow=0008, formatted = 11100011
value = 0228, pow=0008, formatted = 11100100
value = 0229, pow=0008, formatted = 11100101
value = 0230, pow=0008, formatted = 11100110
value = 0231, pow=0008, formatted = 11100111
value = 0232, pow=0008, formatted = 11101000
value = 0233, pow=0008, formatted = 11101001
value = 0234, pow=0008, formatted = 11101010
value = 0235, pow=0008, formatted = 11101011
value = 0236, pow=0008, formatted = 11101100
value = 0237, pow=0008, formatted = 11101101
value = 0238, pow=0008, formatted = 11101110
value = 0239, pow=0008, formatted = 11101111
value = 0240, pow=0008, formatted = 11110000
value = 0241, pow=0008, formatted = 11110001
value = 0242, pow=0008, formatted = 11110010
value = 0243, pow=0008, formatted = 11110011
value = 0244, pow=0008, formatted = 11110100
value = 0245, pow=0008, formatted = 11110101
value = 0246, pow=0008, formatted = 11110110
value = 0247, pow=0008, formatted = 11110111
value = 0248, pow=0008, formatted = 11111000
value = 0249, pow=0008, formatted = 11111001
value = 0250, pow=0008, formatted = 11111010
value = 0251, pow=0008, formatted = 11111011
value = 0252, pow=0008, formatted = 11111100
value = 0253, pow=0008, formatted = 11111101
value = 0254, pow=0008, formatted = 11111110
value = 0255, pow=0008, formatted = 11111111
value = 0256, pow=0012, formatted = 000100000000
value = 0257, pow=0012, formatted = 000100000001
value = 0258, pow=0012, formatted = 000100000010

value = 0511, pow=0012, formatted = 000111111111
value = 0512, pow=0012, formatted = 001000000000
value = 0513, pow=0012, formatted = 001000000001
value = 0514, pow=0012, formatted = 001000000010
value = 0515, pow=0012, formatted = 001000000011
value = 0516, pow=0012, formatted = 001000000100

value = 1021, pow=0012, formatted = 001111111101
value = 1022, pow=0012, formatted = 001111111110
value = 1023, pow=0012, formatted = 001111111111
value = 1024, pow=0012, formatted = 010000000000
value = 1025, pow=0012, formatted = 010000000001
```

Comment: А если при конвертировании будет больше 8 символов? Например `value = 507;`

Comment: @gil9red Любопытный вопрос, попробую переформулировать более строго: подобрать ближайшую максимальную степень двойки.

Comment: @gil9red Прекрасный вопрос, размял мозги на обеде!

Comment: Хороший ответ, плюс вам :)

Comment: Надо бы ещё подумать в сторону того, нельзя ли отказаться от логарифмов - возможно, используя операции битовых сдвигов можно получить тот же результат.

Answer (score 1):

Просто числа принято записывать без ведущих нулей. Если вам нужно отображать **состояние памяти**, то всплывёт еще ряд нюансов, вроде [эндиана](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) и [записи отрицательных чисел](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).

Проще всего будет пройтись по числу с бинарной маской через коньюнкцию

```
public string IntToBinaryString(int number)
{
    const int mask = 1;
    var binary = string.Empty;
    while(number > 0)
    {
        // Logical AND the number and prepend it to the result string
        binary = (number & mask) + binary;
        number = number >> 1;
    }

    return binary;
}
```

или (в простом случае) ваш же результат добить нулями до требуемого разряда ([String.PadLeft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_PadLeft_System_Int32_System_Char_)).

```
binary = "1001";
binary = binary.PadLeft(8, '0');
// binary is now "00001001";
```